# How to select subchildren starting with a specific one via XPath

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I have the following HTML tree (Note that the id is "msg-`uniqueRandomNumber`"):

```
<div class="elements">
    <div class="grp" id="msg-128736"> </div>
    <div class="grp" id="msg-312422"> </div>
    <div class="grp" id="msg-012312"> </div>
    <div class="grp" id="msg-567243"> </div>
</div>
```

I want to match a group of elements where the first one is a specific id.

**Example**: Match every class `grp` starting with `msg-012312`.

Result should be:

```
    <div class="grp" id="msg-012312"> </div>
    <div class="grp" id="msg-567243"> </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choroba's nice explanation and fine answer are correct (+1), but here's a simpler XPath that will work:

```
//div[@class="grp" and not(./following-sibling::div[@id="msg-012312"])]
```

Read as

> Select all of the `grp` `div` elements that do not appear
>   before the `div` with an id of `msg-012312`.

Answer (score 1):

To select a div of the given class and id, use

```
//div[@class="grp" and @id="msg-012312"]
```

To select the following siblings, you can use

```
following-sibling::div[@class="grp"]
```

Putting both nodesets together with the union operator `|`:

```
( //div[@class="grp" and @id="msg-012312"]
| //div[@class="grp" and @id="msg-012312"]/following-sibling::div[@class="grp"] )
```

Comment: Nice explanation and correct answer (+1) but a simpler XPath [is possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33572631/290085).